# comma like \cdot

Tags: spacing, punctuation

What is the `\cdot` alternative for comma, or any other punctuation symbol?
I want to raise comma symbol in a list of fractions to the fraction line. Comma is placed below when used next to fraction.

Answer (score 20):

You can use `\raisebox` to move it where you want. Here is a comparison of the inline `\frac` and the `displaystyle` `\dfrac`. Based on  @GonzaloMedina's suggestions I have provided two versions, each which provides slightly different spacing around the comma:

- one that uses `\mathbin` (spacing similar to `\cdot`) and
- another that uses `\mathpunct` (spacing more like a punctuation)

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\CommaBin}{\mathbin{\raisebox{0.5ex}{,}}}
\newcommand{\CommaPunct}{\mathpunct{\raisebox{0.5ex}{,}}}
\begin{document}

\verb|\mathbin|: $\frac{1}{2} \CommaBin \frac{3}{4} \CommaBin \dfrac{1}{2} \CommaBin \dfrac{3}{4}$

\bigskip
\verb|\mathpunct|: $\frac{1}{2} \CommaPunct \frac{3}{4} \CommaPunct \dfrac{1}{2} \CommaPunct \dfrac{3}{4}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps you could use `\mathop` so `\Comma` would behave as a math operator (like `\cdot`)?

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but now that I've reread the OP's question, perhaps he/she wants the vertically centered comma to act as a punctuation symbol instead of an operator; if this is the case, `\mathpunct` would be better than `\mathop`. Since the intent is not clear (at least to me) you could suggest both options.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina `\cdot` is a `\mathbin`, not a `\mathop`.

Comment: @PeterGrill: it's me again. **egreg** is right; `\cdot` is defined as a binary symbol, not as an operator, so it should be `\mathbin` instead of `\mathop`.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: Updated to use `\mathbin`.