# Command for comma in math or text mode

Tags: punctuation, comma-separated-list

I have the following csv file (*myCSVfile.csv*) which contains header with LaTeX code:

| $T_{1,2}$, | $T_{3}$ |
| --- | --- |
| 100, | 300 |
| 200, | 500 |

In my LaTeX document, I import this table with `\pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=comma,row sep=newline]{myCSVfile.csv}`.

It works well but my csv file is not satisfying for me because some comma are note column separators but just characters in a math expression in header titles, as in: `$T_{1`**`,`**`2}$`

**I there a native command that just print a comma in math mode, e.g.: `$T_{1\comma{}2}$` instead of `$T_{1,2}$` which output nearly the same in the pdf ?**. In text mode it would also be OK for me even if it's not the best solution: `$T_{1\text{\comma{}}2}$`.

I found the `\mathpunct` command [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47212/262081) but there is still a comma when I use it in the csv file : `$T_{1\mathpunct{,}2}$` instead of `$T_{1,2}$` and I get an error when importing with `\pgfplotstabletypeset`...

**I know that I can just put my header title between double quotes `"$T_{1,2}$"` to be sure that the comma in header title will not be interpreted as column separator, but I wonder if there is a way to obtain a comma with a native command in math mode or even in text mode.**

## MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable,filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{myCSVfile.csv}
$T_{1,2}$, $T_{3}$
100,      300     
200,      500     
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
    \pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep = comma,row sep=newline]{myCSVfile.csv}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\newcommand{\comma}{,}`

Comment: Thanks for your comment. What appends if I give my csv file to someone else, I need to tell this person what `\comma` is ? I would prefer more "portable" solution...

Comment: Use the quotes. There is no “self-defining command”

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `"$T_{1,2}$"` as that will be easily understood by any software or human reading the csv file. However comma is ASCII decimal 44, hex 2C so you can use `^^2c` if you wish:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable,filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{myCSVfile.csv}
$T_{1^^2c 2}$, $T_{3}$
100,      300     
200,      500     
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
    \pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep = comma,row sep=newline]{myCSVfile.csv}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot ! Could you explain the `^^2c` syntax ? Especially the `^^` ?

Comment: @SylvainRigal this is low level syntax `^^` followed by a captital shifts the character code by 64 so `^^M` is control-m, or `^^` followed by two lowercase hex digits is that character.  This is at a very early stage, before tokenization, eg `\be^^67in` is `\begin` because `g` is ascii hex 67